# PHP display logic to cut duplicates

Tags: php

I have the following example of a MySQL db while loop of results, simply this:

```
echo '<table class="profileTable">
            <tr>
                <td>folder</td>
                <td>Link</td>
                <td>actions</td>
            </tr>';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo '<tr><td>'.$row[name].'</td><td><a href="'.$row[url].'">'.$row[title].'</a></td><td>actions here</td></tr>';

    }
```

OUTPUTS this:

```
Coding  The Simpsons in CSS         actions here
Coding  Google SEO starter guide    actions here
Coding  PHPGang Programming Blog    actions here
Shop    Amazon                      actions here
```

But what I want is the first col to only show when its different to previous col val e.g.:

```
Coding  The Simpsons in CSS         actions here
        Google SEO starter guide    actions here
        PHPGang Programming Blog    actions here
Shop    Amazon                      actions here
```

is this possible? I would presume you have to check the val of the first col each time but I cannot work out the logic to blank the column if its the same for however many times it is.

Comment: Yup, that is pretty much the way. See whether the current value matches the last value, and suppress it if it does

Comment: I don't think there is any reason for you to be this pompous to the first closevoter. This is essentially a question asking for code and those aren't really on topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $test = $row[name];
    echo '<tr><td>';
    if($test != $test2) {
        echo $row[name];}else{echo '&nbsp;';
    }

    echo '</td><td><a href="'.$row[url].'">'.$row[title].'</a></td><td>actions here</td></tr>';
    $test2 = $test;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, this was driving me insane after going around the loop many times with differing scenarios!

Comment: Happy to be of assistance!